# Android build fails with unknown reason after upgrading android-sdk

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build

I am working with old version `Unity 4.0` to use some old plugin. After my wrong step of upgrading Android SDK, Unity gives a error and it doesn't build the Unity project at all.

I read it is the typical error by upgrading Android SDK, rev 21 to rev 22. And it shows

```
Error building Player: Exception: Android (invocation failed) Error* Unknown error
```

Then I tried to downgrade Android SDK to rev21, also reinstall Unity and Eclipse(just in case), but all did not work.

Do you have any suggestion to recover this trouble?

According to SDK manager my Android SDK contains:

- Android SDK Tools: Rev.21
- Platform-tools: 19.0.1
- API: 15, 14
- Extras: Android Support Library

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it can't find aapt.exe file inside \androidsdk\tools try copying aapt.exe from \androidsdk\build-tools\19.0.1 (what ever version) you have to tools

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried to copy aapt.exe, but does not work.

Do I need build-tools to build the project? Android-sdk manager of rev 21 does show any build-tools for installing.